# Pandas Loc string giving KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am trying to pass into a url a date in the format 2015-12-20, search the pandas dataframe and do a model.predict on it.

The problem is that I am trying to convert a working code from the jupyter lab into the .py file in order to run everything on the flask server and following I can not transfer.

The following code only works if the 'Date' column is converted to datetime. If it is in object format, the following code also doesn't work.

```
data.loc[2015-12-06]
```

The above works but the following gives an error:

```
data.loc['2015-12-06']

KeyError: '2015-12-06'
```

How do I pass in the 2015-12-06 not as string for the .loc to work?

```
print(data.head(5).to_dict())

{'Date': {0: '2015-12-27', 1: '2015-12-20', 2: '2015-12-13', 3: '2015-12-06', 4: '2015-11-29'}, 'Total Volume': {0: 64236.62, 1: 54876.98, 2: 118220.22, 3: 78992.15, 4: 51039.6}, '4046': {0: 1036.74, 1: 674.28, 2: 794.7, 3: 1132.0, 4: 941.48}, '4225': {0: 54454.85, 1: 44638.81, 2: 109149.67, 3: 71976.41, 4: 43838.39}, '4770': {0: 48.16, 1: 58.33, 2: 130.5, 3: 72.58, 4: 75.78}, 'Total Bags': {0: 8696.87, 1: 9505.56, 2: 8145.35, 3: 5811.16, 4: 6183.95}, 'Small Bags': {0: 8603.62, 1: 9408.07, 2: 8042.21, 3: 5677.4, 4: 5986.26}, 'Large Bags': {0: 93.25, 1: 97.49, 2: 103.14, 3: 133.76, 4: 197.69}, 'XLarge Bags': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'type': {0: 'conventional', 1: 'conventional', 2: 'conventional', 3: 'conventional', 4: 'conventional'}, 'year': {0: 2015, 1: 2015, 2: 2015, 3: 2015, 4: 2015}, 'region': {0: 'Albany', 1: 'Albany', 2: 'Albany', 3: 'Albany', 4: 'Albany'}}
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your data with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` ?

Comment: Done. It is in the main body.